# How can I assignin filenames correctly while applying ImageFilters in Python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to use pillow to apply kernals to .jpg images in python and I'm trying to process an entire image set at once. I have a script here that will iterate through the training set, apply the edge finding filter, and save the result in a different folder. Whenever I try to do that using the .save command it throw an error telling me there is no such file as the one I'm saving it to. The thing is, I'm trying to create that file. It doesn't do this when I've got a definite file name, only when I'm trying to do it iterativly. Can anyone see what the problem here is?

```
import PIL
import os
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter
from PIL.ImageFilter import (FIND_EDGES)

num = 1
path = "/home/<me>/Desktop/<my documents>/<my project>/Training Set Cars/"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
for filename in dirs:
    print(filename)
    im = Image.open(path + filename)
    aString = str(num)
    print("/home/<me>/Desktop/<my documents>/<my project>/Training Car Edges/%s.jpg" % aString)
  ERROR HERE>>> im.filter(FIND_EDGES).save("/home/<me>/Desktop/<my documents>/<my project>/Training Car Edges/%s.jpg" % aString)
    num += 1
```

Comment: Does the "Training Car Edges" directory exist?

Comment: Oh my God, it's got an s. Training Cars Edges. It works perfectly now. I feel so dumb right now. In my defense, it is very late.

Comment: For future reference, when you have long strings like these that you expect to use a lot, declare them as a global variable once at the top of your file. Also, for filesystem access, you should use `os.path.exists` to make sure you're accessing a real thing.